# I am using the same logic that I used to validate the name to the email but for some reason it's not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to create a validation for name and email but for some reason the email validation is not working. If remove my name validation it will work but it doesn't work together.As well as if I enter my name and leave the email empty it still does not send an alert.

```js
function validations(form) {
  var n = document.getElementById("nam").value;
  if (n == "") {
    alert("Please enter Name");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

  var em2 = document.getElementById("em1").value;
  if (em2 == "") {
    alert("Please enter EMAIL");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return validations(this);">
  <div class="name">
    Name : <input type="text" id="nam" name="fullName">
  </div>
  <div class="em">
    Email : <input type="email" name="Email" id="em1">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: because of `else {
    return true;
  }` after the first validation. If the name field is filled in, the method ends due to this clause. It never ever runs the code to validate the email. Wait until you've validated all the fields before you decide what to return.

Comment: But if you just want to validate whether someone completed the field, you can simply add the `required` attribute to the element. No need for JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation . Other standard types of validation can also be performed in this way, potentially saving you lots of fiddly code.

Answer (score 3):

Your function always returns after checking the `nam`, whether its valid or not. You should early-return `false` if the `nam` isn't valid, but hold off with returning `true` until you've validated the entire form. E.g.:

```
function validations(form) {
    // Check the name
    var n = document.getElementById("nam").value; 
    if (n == ""){
        alert("Please enter Name");
        return false ;
    }

    // Check the email
    var em2 = document.getElementById("em1").value; 
    if (em2 == ""){
        alert("Please enter EMAIL");
        return false ;
    } 

    // If we reached here, both the name and email are OK
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more easy just use the HTML input `type="email"` with the attribut `required`. It will then verify that the user enter a valid email.

See the doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/email)